# Nodejs send files from one nodejs server to another

Tags: node.js, file, http, request, multipartform-data

How can I emulate sending the multipart form data from one nodejs server to another, with custom files on 1st  server, which are parsed from form submitted to 1st server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post file from one server to another,using node.js , needle , busboy/multer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349885/post-file-from-one-server-to-another-using-node-js-needle-busboy-multer)