# Post file from one server to another,using node.js , needle , busboy/multer

Tags: node.js, multer, busboy

I would like to move a small image from one server to another (both running node). As I search, I haven't found enough. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315630/how-to-transfer-a-file-from-one-server-to-another-using-node-js) post remains unanswered.

As I started experimenting I wrote the following to the first server :

```
app.post("/move_img", function(req, res) {
    console.log("post handled");
    fs.readFile(__dirname + "/img_to_move.jpg", function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(data);
        needle.post(server2 + "/post_img", {
           data: data,
           name : "test.jpg"
        }, function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            res.send("ok");
        });
    });  
});
```

This part seems to be working as I could be writing the data in the same server (using fs.writeFile) recreate the img.

Now as I am trying to handle the post in the other server I have a problem.

Server2:

```
app.post('/post_img', [ multer({ dest: './uploads/images'}), function(req, res) {

    console.log("body ",req.body) // form fields
    console.log("files ",req.files) // form files
    res.send("got it");
}]);
```

This way i get an empty object in the files and the following in the body:   `{ 'headers[Content-Type]': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'headers[Content-Length]': '45009' }`

I think I could use busboy as an alternative but I can't make it to work. Any advice, tutorial would be welcome.

Comment: That's my problem i don't know, where to start. I should use needle to post to another server holding the img in the post data, or should i look into something else?

Comment: @vanadium i would prefer to do it programmatically and not to use linux commands in my code. (if I understand correctly the solution you provide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the following code,

server1 (using needle) :

```
app.post("/move_img", function(req, res) {
    console.log("post handled")

    var data = {
        image:{
        file: __dirname + "/img_to_move.jpg",
        content_type: "image/jpeg"}
    }

    needle.post(server2 + "/post_img", data, {
        multipart: true
    }, function(err,result) {
        console.log("result", result.body);
    });
})
```

Server 2:

```
app.use('/post_img',multer({
    dest: '.uploads/images',
    rename: function(fieldname, filename) {
        return filename;
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function(file) {
        console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...')
    },
    onFileUploadComplete: function(file) {
        console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path)
    }
}));

app.post('/post_img', function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.files);
    res.send("File uploaded.");

});
```

An alternative for the server 1 is the following (using form-data module):

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append('name', 'imgTest.jpg');
form.append('my_file', fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/img_to_move.jpg"));

form.submit(frontend + "/post_img", function(err, result) {
    // res – response object (http.IncomingMessage)  //
    console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply read your file from the first server with the function [readFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) and then write it to the other server with the function [writeFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780560/node-js-upload-files-to-server-without-additionals-frameworks/27585910#27585910) you can see use of both functions in one of my servers.

Comment: This could be done. How about the transition of the files from one server to another. p.s. I am editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';

const express   = require('express');
const multer= require('multer');
const concat = require('concat-stream');
const request = require('request');

const router = express.Router();

function HttpRelay (opts) {}


HttpRelay.prototype._handleFile = function _handleFile (req, file, cb) {
    file.stream.pipe(concat({ encoding: 'buffer' }, function (data) {
        const r = request.post('/Endpoint you want to upload file', function (err, resp, body) {

            if (err) return cb(err);
            req.relayresponse=body;
            cb(null, {});
        });

        const form = r.form();
        form.append('uploaded_file', data, {
            filename: file.originalname,
            contentType: file.mimetype
        });
    }))
};

HttpRelay.prototype._removeFile = function _removeFile (req, file, cb) {
    console.log('hello');
    cb(null);
};

const relayUpload = multer({ storage: new HttpRelay() }).any();

router.post('/uploadMsgFile', function(req, res) {
    relayUpload(req, res, function(err) {

        res.send(req.relayresponse);

    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

see multer does all the tricks for you.
you just have to make sure you use no middle-ware but multer to upload files in your node starting point.
Hope it does the tricks for you also.